# Split log data with php preg_match

Tags: php, regex

my task is to analyze log files with PHP-script.
I'm going to use REGEX in order to split log records for further analyses.
Log records are like following:

```
param1=val1;param2=val2;param3=val3;[int1Param1=int1Val1;int1Param2=int1Val2;][int2Param1=int2Val1;int2Param2=int2Val2;][int3Param1=int3Val1;int3Param2=int3Val2;]param4=val4;
```

so, I have set of parameters and values I have to analyze, and I have no problem with this part.
My concern is "session data" which is inside series of square brackets between param3 and param4. The issue is that I have no idea how much records I'll have in this part (it can be 0 or more of such records in this part).
I'm identifying this part with following regex:

```
(\[[^\]\[]+\])*
```

It perfectly identifies complete string between "param3=val3;" and "param4=val4;" and returns it as "0" element of preg_match's $matches array. What I need is to get also all this brackets as array elements, for further analyses of its content, but $matches contains only 2 elements: "0" - whale string; "1" - last "brackets".
Any ideas?
Thanks Dennis.

Comment: Difficult to understand your problem. Can you explain clearly what are your expected matches from above string.

Comment: Just remove the * and it will work... It has nothing to do there :)

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/tllFLowSBm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` on the string like so:

```
preg_match_all("/\[[^][]+\]/", $log, $results);
print_r($results);
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [int1Param1=int1Val1;int1Param2=int1Val2;]
            [1] => [int2Param1=int2Val1;int2Param2=int2Val2;]
            [2] => [int3Param1=int3Val1;int3Param2=int3Val2;]
        )
)
```

[Demo here](https://eval.in/45188).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

```
$pattern = '~(?:(?<new>\[)|\G(?!^))(?<key>[^]=]++)=(?<val>[^][;]++);~';
$subject = 'param1=val1;param2=val2;param3=val3;[int1Param1=int1Val1;int1Param2=int1Val2;][int2Param1=int2Val1;int2Param2=int2Val2;][int3Param1=int3Val1;int3Param2=int3Val2;]param4=val4;';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $i=0;    
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if ($match['new']) $i++;
        $result[$i][$match['key']]=$match['val'];
    }
    print_r($result);
}
```

pattern explanation:

```
~                 # pattern delimiter
(?:               # open a non-capturing group
    (?<new>\[)    # the named group "new" contains a possible "[". It's useful
                  # to know when a new content in square brackets begins.
  |               # or
    \G(?!^)       # a match (that can't be at the start of the string)
                  # contiguous (\G) to a precedent match 
)                 # close the atomic group
(?<key>[^]=]++)   # named group "key"
=
(?<val>[^][;]++)  # named group "val"
;
~
```

the alternative in the atomic group describe to possibilities. The first is `[` to match the first pair key/value inside square brackets. Then the second (and others) which is forced to be contiguous to a precedent match can succeed.